# How do I use a csv time column as the x-axis in C3.js?

Tags: c3.js

I have a datafile in csv format. I need to use the second column as the x-axis. The column is in hh:mm:ss format. Can I do a 12 hour format?
I have tried:

```
<SCRIPT>
var chart = c3.generate({
            bindto: '#chart',
    data: {

    x: 'time12',
    xFormat:  '%H:%M:%S',
    url: 'dataXY_11-21-2016.csv',
    type: 'line'
    },
 });

axis: {
        y: {
            max: 350,
            min: 0,
            // Range includes padding, set 0 if no padding needed
            // padding: {top:0, bottom:0}
        }
    }
});
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining your x-axis as a timeseries.
Your config should look like this (columns only for demonstration):

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        x: 'time12',
        xFormat: '%H:%M:%S',
        columns: [
            ['data', 90,250,180,320,100],
            ['time12', '12:31:25', '13:12:54','14:27:21', '14:53:42', '15:51:47']
            ],
        type: 'line'

    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type:'timeseries',
            tick:{
                format: '%H:%M:%S'
            }
        },
        y: {
            max: 350,
            min: 0
      }
    }

});
```

You only have to adjust your `xFormat`. If you have "`08:12:23 PM`", use "`%H:%M:%S %p`" instead.
For more information you can visit the c3 docs or take a look at the [formatting options](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md) in d3.

Comment: This is what I used and did not work: <script>
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
    x: 'time12', // 'time12'  header  12-hour clock column use as 'X'
    xFormat:  '%H:%M:%S',
    url: 'dataXY_11-21-2016.csv', 
    type: 'line'
    },

// the 'time12' column increments every 30 seconds 
// and includes 'AM' and 'PM'
axis: {
    x: {
    type:'timeseries', 
    tick:{
            format: '%H:%M:%S',
         }
        }
      } 
 
axis: {
        y: {
            max: 350,
            min: 0,
        }
    }
});

Comment: this config looks wrong, i've updated my answer to be more specific. please take a look at the time formatting options from d3. if it still doesn't work provide more information like an example of the csv you are using

Comment: Where you're using columns, I import a csv file. That seems to be a major problem for me. My data files have fifteen columns and, typically, 1200 rows. When I replaced the columns section with a url  specification, the graph has all the data bunched up at zero and the time at zero is '19:00:00'.

Comment: The first two lines of the csv:  time,time12,date,PV array voltage(V),PV array current(A),PV array power(W),Battery voltage(V),Battery charging current(A),Battery charging power(W),Load voltage(V),Load current(A),Load power(W),Battery temperature(°C),Charger temperature(°C),Heat sink temperature(°C),Battery SOC(%),Remote battery temperature(°C),System rated voltage(V),Battery status,Equipment status,azimuth,elevation
06:55:00,06:55:00 AM,2016-11-21,23.9,0,0,24.12,0,0,24.12,0.05,1.2,25,4.74,4.74,17,25,24,2,1,112.00934352633543 , -2.5857869394918533

Comment: The AM or PM in 'time12' may be a problem. I added the d3 '%p' AM/PM format but, while the time is now expanded correctly and AM/PM is applied correctly, the actual time is presented in 24-hour format

Comment: As I said AM or PM shouldn't be the problem, xFormat: '%H:%M:%S %p' works fine, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, look in my last post. I solved the 24-hour clock problem by changing '%H' to '%I'. Thanks for your help. There is one closely related issue of thinning out the number of entries. Graphing every nth row, or , row selection, would be an improvement as would column selection.

Comment: Thanks again, Akoya.